# Store value in session and retrieve in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple wholesale page for my company products. in this products i have created quotation button, and attached quotation form.
problem is- When i open  quotation form respectively product name auto fill in this form. IT IS POSSIBLE?

```
<label for="ContactFormProduct"><strong>Select a Product</strong></label> 
<select id="ContactFormProduct" name="contact[Product]"> <option> Product Name </option> 
<option> BS SKYCAST-(BULK) </option> <option> BS Futura PCX 107-(BULK) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please, attach a snippet.

Comment: <label for="ContactFormProduct"><strong>Select a Product</strong></label>
       <select id="ContactFormProduct" name="contact[Product]">
       <option> Product Name </option>
       <option> BS SKYCAST-(BULK) </option>
       <option> BS Futura PCX 107-(BULK) </option>
      
       </select>

Comment: right now i am doing this for product name on quotation form.

Comment: @adam azad- how can we store product name in session and get another page,i want to display product name in  text box on quotation form.

Answer (score 1):

u can use localstorage for small data

```
<label for="ContactFormProduct"><strong>Select a Product</strong></label> 
<select id="ContactFormProduct" name="contact[Product]"> 
<option> Product Name </option> 
<option> BS SKYCAST-(BULK) </option> 
<option> BS Futura PCX 107-(BULK) </option>
</select>

<script>
    var product = $('#ContactFormProduct').val();
    localStorage.setItem('myproduct', product);

    //next page 
    var getproduct = localStorage.getItem("myproduct");
</script>
```

Comment: all the products name store in {{product.title}}